# Django - save() update on duplicate key

Tags: django, save, unique-constraint, insert-update

I have little application which allows a user to rate a video.

The user can rate only once.
So I have defined the uniqueness on the model.

But he should be able change his rate.
So the `save()` should update on duplicate key

```
class VideoRate(models.Model):
  """Users can Rate each Video on the criterias defined for the topic"""
  user = models.ForeignKey(User)
  video = models.ForeignKey(VideoFile)
  crit = models.ForeignKey(VideoCrit)
  rate = models.DecimalField(max_digits=2, decimal_places=1, choices=RATE_CHOICES)
  class Meta:
    unique_together = (('user', 'video', 'crit'),)
    verbose_name = 'Video Rating'
```

If I

```
rate = VideoRate(user_id=1, video_id=1, crit_id=1, rate=2)
rate.save()
```

It's saving the rating, but if I

```
rate = VideoRate(user_id=1, video_id=1, crit_id=1, rate=3)
rate.save()
```

I get the normal error

```
IntegrityError: (1062, "Duplicate entry '1-1-1' for key 'user_id'")
```

Even if I use `force_update=True` (since based only on primary keys)

Is there a way to update the rating if it already exists without having to check data before ?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

To update an existing rating, you actually have to have the one you want to update. If you know the object may not exist, use `get_or_create`:

```
rate, created = VideoRate.objects.get_or_create(user_id=1, video_id=1, crit_id=1)
rate.rate = 2
rate.save()
```

You can short-cut the process by using `update()`:

```
VideoRate.objects.filter(user_id=1, video_id=1, crit_id=1).update(rate=2)
```

But this will silently fail if the rating does not exist - it won't create one.

Comment: +1: First option will do 2 or 3 queries, while the second will do 1.

Comment: Seems not bad. You mean Django can't perform a `INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...` ?

Comment: No, because that's a MySQL-specific extension, and Django works with a range of databases.

Comment: How about adding a put() method to the base model in conjunction with the use of unique_together? To me that looks cleaner than using get_or_create().

Comment: You can do it, just use low level API like: connection.cursor().execute(sql) where sql is "INSERT INTO example (a, b, c) VALUES (1,2,3) ON DUPLICATE KEY
UPDATE a = VALUES(a), b = VALUES(b), c = VALUES(c);"

Answer (score 11):

First, you must check if the rating exists. So you may either use what **Daniel Roseman** said or use **exists**, but you can not solve this with a simple update since update do not create new records...

```
rating = 2
rate, created = VideoRate.objects.get_or_create(user_id=1, video_id=1, crit_id=1,
    defaults={'rate':rating})#if create, also save the rate infdormation

if not created:# update
    rate.rate = rating
    rate.save()
```

You can use **defaults** to pass exrta arguments, so if it is an **insert**, database record will be created with all required information and you do not need to update it again...

[Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.get_or_create)

**Update:** This answer is quite old just like the question. As @peterthomassen mention, Django now have [update_or_create()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#update-or-create) method

Comment: The `defaults` keyword is also very interesting

Comment: The values from the `defaults` argument are also used for updating in the case where the object does not need to be created in the database, see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#update-or-create. Consequently, the `if` part of your code is no-op.

Comment: @peterthomassen thanks for the notification. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 3):

[Django 4.1](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create) has added the support for such conflicts. In the backend, it runs a `INSERT...ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` query.

Example of above in a single query:

```py
rate = VideoRate(user_id=1, video_id=1, crit_id=1, rate=2)
rate.save()

# updating rate object if it exists, else create one
rate = VideoRate(user_id=1, video_id=1, crit_id=1, rate=3)
VideoRate.objects.bulk_create(
    [rate],
    update_conflicts=True,
    update_fields=['rate']
)
```