# Where do I put methods that perform create_if_missing or update_if_exists function in django?

Tags: python, django

In what location should I place methods that perform:

- Create this row if it is missing
- Update the row if it exists

for a django model ?

Additionally since I am using the default transaction scheme of django, this might introduce race conditions. How do I prevent that ?

Answer (score 1):

Django has this built-in: [`get_or_create`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create).

Answer (score 1):

The answer is [get_or_create](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6382806/django-save-update-on-duplicate-key).

I suppose it is obligatory to link to their [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create) as well.