# MySQL update if exist else insert

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to insert information to DB, but if information "user_id" already exist update, like this:  (the problem is user_id isn't the KEY)

```
INSERT INTO access_token 
        (id,access_token,user_id)
VALUES
        (1062371433,106237146,10623714)
ON DUPLICATE user_id     <=== receive error in this line
        UPDATE
            access_token = VALUES(access_token)
```

but receive error in line 5,

how to fix it?

thanks,

Comment: possible duplicate of [Insert to table or update if exists (MySQL)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4205181/insert-to-table-or-update-if-exists-mysql)

Comment: Maybe the link below will help you
Click [here]:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6382806/django-save-update-on-duplicate-key

Comment: Sounds like you might need a unique constraint on `user_id`?  Then update your syntax to `ON DUPLICATE KEY`...

Comment: @Hamatti the problem is "user_id" isn't the table KEY and not unique

Comment: I think on Insert on duplicate key update is what you should be looking for.

Comment: you can't do it by on duplicate because it is not a key So, you have to do it manually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use this:

[INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

```
INSERT INTO access_token 
    (id,access_token,user_id)
VALUES
    (1062371433,106237146,10623714)
ON DUPLICATE KEY
    UPDATE
        access_token = VALUES(access_token);
```

Comment: the problem is user_id isn't the key

Comment: and you can't even make it a UNIQUE key?

Comment: then write a small piece of procedure to handle this. I guess any statement wouldn't help in this situation!

Answer (score 0):

```
set @founded_id=(select user_id from access_token  where user_id='10623714');


if(@founded_id='10623714')then
update access_token  set ............

else
INSERT INTO access_token 
        (id,access_token,user_id)
VALUES
        (1062371433,106237146,10623714)
```